# How does the body regenerate nerves?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience

If neurons come from neuroblasts which come from neuro stem cells that are embryonic, how is it possible for an adult to regenerate nerve tissue? Are neuro stem cells created during later stages of life, and, if so, where? Or is it solely a finite repository of stem cells somewhere?